# Unable to determine the principal end of an association when more than one child members

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

```
public class Ninja
{ 
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public Ninja BestFriend { get; set; }
    //public Ninja Enemy { get; set; }
}
```

When i try to update my database this will work only with one ninja member. If i try to include more than one, the Ninja Enemy, i get an error. (im looking for an explanation to why this is as much as a solution.)

> Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'NinjaDomain.Classes.Ninja' and 'NinjaDomain.Classes.Ninja'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations.

Comment: You might need a new table, or tell the relation in the `modelBuilder`. Tell the fields also which one is required and which one is optional.

Comment: Gottcha. Actually im looking for an explanation to why this is as much as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
public class Ninja
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Ninja BestFriend { get; set; }
    public virtual Ninja Enemy { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("BestFriend")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ninja> whoseBestFriend { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("Enemy")]
    public virtual ICollection<Ninja> whoseEnemy { get; set; }
}
```

Last two properties determine *principal end of an association between the types 'NinjaDomain.Classes.Ninja' and 'NinjaDomain.Classes.Ninja'*. Each of `Ninja` now know for who he is `Enemy` and for who he is `BestFriend`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks! However i have a question. If i only have one member in the class that is of type Ninja, lets say BestFriend, i can update de DB without errors. How come? I dont get it.

Comment: I agree, it is strange, furthermore if you try to add third `Ninja` property to your initial class or several new, you will see that all will be ok even without `ICollection`. May be it is bug or it is something what we don't know about EF.